# Can not access object from event handler in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
question = {
    quest : "How old am I?",
    answers : [17,18,20,25],
    correct : 17,
}

checkAnswer(){
    var usersAnswer = document.getElementById('ans-1').textContent;
    var answer = this.question.correct;
    if(usersAnswer==answer){
        alert('correct')
    }else{
        alert('u lost')
    }
}
```

With this code, i can't access object from event handler in ReactJS. 
I get this error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property `question` of `undefined`
>   P.S i'm begginer

Comment: It's the classic `this` problem; 1. bind `this` to the functions or 2. use `checkAnswer = () => {` or 3. use `attribute={() => this.checkAnswer}`

Comment: Either use arrow functions or bind `this` to the function

Comment: Why are you using a DOM selector like that in a React component method? You should add your complete component code for us to fully understand what's going on here.

Comment: `this.checkAnswer = this.checkAnswer.bind(this);`

Comment: This is explained in the docs btw: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html (also, typing into the input field is supposed to update the `state`, which can then be used to compare to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to wrong `this` binding. You can use [**Arrow Function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
checkAnswer = () => {
    var usersAnswer = document.getElementById('ans-1').textContent;
    var answer = this.question.correct;
    if(usersAnswer==answer){
        alert('correct')
    }else{
        alert('u lost')
    }
}
```

You can also use [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) instead of arrow function. You just need to add `this.checkAnswer.bind(this)`. instead if `this.checkAnswer.bind` where you are setting the handler